# SQL Remove line break on single variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that returns a line of HTML text. When I copy the results to Excel, the column formats the spreadsheet with the HTML code.

I am trying to remove the line breaks so the result remains in one line.

I managed to remove the <br> using the code below, but now the output condenses all of the results into one line, not just the one column.

E.g.

**Desired Result**

```
<br>Column1 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Column2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Column3
<br>A&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;p&gt;I have a question&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Here is the answer to my question&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/html&gt;
<br>B&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;p&gt;Hello world&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;This is a response&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/html&gt;
<br>C&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;p&gt;Do you have another question&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;I have another question&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/html&gt;
```

**Current Result**

```
A 1 &lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;p&gt;I have a question&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Here is the answer to my question&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/html&gt;B 2 &lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;p&gt;Hello world&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;This is a response&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/html&gt;C 3 &lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;p&gt;Do you have another question&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;I have another question&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/html&gt;
```

**Code Tried So Far** 

(Column3 contains the HTML)

```
SELECT
Column1
,Column2
,REPLACE(CAST(Column3 AS CHAR), '<br%','')
FROM
Table1
WHERE
CAST(Column3 AS VARCHAR(MAX) LIKE '%m%'
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking or saying here. You say that your data has HTML in `Column3`, but there is no HTML in `Column3`. There's also no line breaks in the data.

Comment: Could you do string_split() on '<br'?

Comment: I was trying to keep the question simple, but I see how it was confusing. I've added HTML to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove Carriage return and line feed characters with `REPLACE`:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(YourColumn,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),'')
```

Comment: This returns the same result as what I tried; everything still gets condensed into one row when I copy the SQL results to Excel.